# Figure out code from what module is "use"d in a large rust project (servo)

Tags: rust, servo

I'm trying to read the code of [servo](https://github.com/servo/servo/). As an example, I'm looking at [this code in layout_task.rs](https://github.com/servo/servo/blame/master/components/layout/layout_task.rs#L79):

```
use url::Url;
```

..and I want to know which code this refers to (the answer is [rust-url](https://github.com/servo/rust-url/blame/master/src/lib.rs#L167)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the [Rust reference §6.1.2.2 Use declarations](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#use-declarations),

> the paths contained in `use` items are **relative to the crate root** [...]
>
> **It is also possible to use `self` and `super` at the beginning of a `use` item** to refer to the current and direct parent modules respectively.
>
> All rules regarding accessing declared modules in `use` declarations apply to both module declarations and `extern crate` declarations.

The reference ([§5 Crates and source files](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#crates-and-source-files)) does not explicitly say what a "crate root" is, but it does share that:

> A crate contains a tree of nested module scopes. The top level of this tree is a module that is anonymous [...] The Rust compiler is always invoked with a single source file as input, and always produces a single output crate. The processing of that source file may result in other source files being loaded as modules.

So it seems that to find the **crate root** that the current file (layout_task.rs) belongs to, we need to figure out what source file `rustc` is invoked with when building the crate. With Cargo this is specified in [Cargo.toml](http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#configuring-a-target) and defaults to `src/lib.rs`:

```
[lib]
path = "src/lib.rs"
```

In my case, here's [Cargo.toml](https://github.com/servo/servo/blob/a7208869f2903e36f9b2f540b55b50283d7df466/components/layout/Cargo.toml#L6) and the [lib.rs](https://github.com/servo/servo/blob/a7208869f2903e36f9b2f540b55b50283d7df466/components/layout/lib.rs#L56) has:

```
extern crate url;
pub mod layout_task;
```

So far so good. To find out what the `extern crate` refers to, we need to look at [Cargo.toml](https://github.com/servo/servo/blob/a7208869f2903e36f9b2f540b55b50283d7df466/components/layout/Cargo.toml#L65) again:

```
[dependencies.url]
version = "0.2"
```

The [cargo docs](http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#the-dependencies-sections) claim that *"Dependencies from crates.io are not declared with separate sections"*, but apparently they can be... So we look the package up on crates.io: https://crates.io/crates/url